# Как сделать текст внутри чекбокса

Tags: html, css

CSS

```
 #word_opts{
      text:cjhabs;
      width: 100px;
      height: 24px;
      vertical-align: -6.5px;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      -moz-appearance: none;
      background:  rgba(153, 153, 153, 1);
      outline: none;
      border-radius: 19px;
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 12px rgba(0,0,0, .2);
      transition: 0.2s;
      position: relative;
    }

    #word_opts:checked[type="checkbox"] {
      background: #7F2929;
    }
```

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="word_opts" name="test"> *случайное*</input>
```

[пример](https://codepen.io/niko129e1982/pen/vQwjdK)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
#word_opts {
  text: cjhabs;
  width: 100px;
  height: 24px;
  vertical-align: -6.5px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  background: rgba(153, 153, 153, 1);
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 19px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  transition: 0.2s;
  position: relative;
}

label input[type="checkbox"]:checked + #word_opts {
  background: #7F2929;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="test" style="display:none"/>
  <span id="word_opts">*случайное*</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<style>
input[type="checkbox"] {display:none;}
input[type="checkbox"] + label:before {content:"☐";}
input:checked + label:before {content:"☑";}
label:hover {color:blue;cursor:pointer;}
</style>

<input id="check" type="checkbox" /><label for="check"> Случайное</label>
```